# How do you find the date that you want from one of Dictionary values?

Tags: c#, dictionary, datetime

As the title suggests, How do you find date that you want from one of the dictionary values which is date time?

I tried many time in an attempt to find such date but it said that date is not found even it is in one of the values!

What to do?

```
public static void ListAllSalesByDate()
{
   int orderCount = 0;
   double totalCount = 0;

   DateTime input;

   int id = 0;

   Console.Write("Enter the date: ");
   if (DateTime.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input))
   {
      foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Sale> sale in sales)
      {
         if (sale.Value.Today == input)
         {
            id = sale.Key;

         }
      }
      if (sales.ContainsKey(id))
      {

         for (int i = 0; i <= sales.Count; i++)
         {
            orderCount++;

            Console.WriteLine("\nOrder(s) Found for {0}!\n", input.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));

            Console.WriteLine("Order ID:  Total:");
            Console.WriteLine("=========  =======");
            Console.WriteLine($"{sales[id].OrderID:D5}  {sales[id].Finaltotal:C}");

            totalCount += sales[i].Finaltotal;

            Console.WriteLine($"{orderCount} order(s) found for a total of {totalCount:C} on {sales[id].Today}");
         }
      }
      else
      {
         Console.WriteLine($"\nthe date of {input.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")} was not found. Try again.\n");
      }
   }
   else
   {
      Console.WriteLine($"\nthe date of {input.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")} was not found. Try again.\n");
   }
}
```

Comment: Date component yes

Comment: Try to remove the time part either completely of as much of it as suits you. The fractons of a second will make terrible keys to look up! before filling the Dictionary!

Comment: The problem is likely that `sale.Value.Today` returns current Date, you should use: `sale.Value.Date`.

Comment: You have two cases that ouput `the date of {input.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")} was not found`. Which is being hit? The answer to the question will change depending on that

Comment: Else in If statement of Sales.ContainsKEy

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to compare just the Date Component of a `DateTime` and want the `KeyValuePair`, just use [`FirstOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=net-5.0)

> Returns the first element of the sequence that satisfies a condition
> or a default value if no such element is found.

```
var result = sales.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.Date == input.Date);

if(result != null)
{
   // you have found the dictionary entry
   var id = result.Key;
   ...
}
else
{
   // not found
}
```

If there can be more than one Date that matches, you can use [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Where__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__)

> Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate.

```
var results = sales.Where(x => x.Value.Date == input.Date).ToList();

if(!results.Any())
{
   foreach(var entry in results)
   {
       var id = result.Key;
      ...
   }
}
else
{
   // not found
}
```